Яндекс Локатор ошибка invalid api_key
Я создал валидный API для запроса в Яндекс Локатор. Использую IP address моего сайта на который я сделал ключ. Проверил на валидность XML. Делаю запрос к локатору.

curl -X POST "http://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation" -d "xml=<ya_lbs_request><common><version>1.0</version><api_key>ТУТМОЙАПИКЛЮЧ==</api_key></common><gsm_cells><cell><countrycode>250</countrycode><operatorid>2</operatorid><cellid>197403650</cellid><lac>9900</lac><signal_strength>-80</signal_strength><age>1000</age></cell></gsm_cells><ip><address_v4>ТУТМОЙИПАДРЕС</address_v4></ip></ya_lbs_request>"

Получаю ошибку от Локатора
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<error code="8">invalid api_key</error>

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Убедитесь, что ключ указан верно и от нужного сервиса. Вижу, что ключ получен недавно, в сервисе существует задержка активации ключа в 15 минут.

Внизу страницы по локатора есть инструкция FAQ о том, что нужно активировать API в личном кабинете. Надо было ее выполнить. Спасибо!
